# Jenkins - Bash if else statement variable not found

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am having a steps in Jenkins pipeline to read my test passing result and fail the  Stage if rate lower than 95%.
Here's the code

```
sh ''' #!/bin/bash -xe
                PASS= `cat index.txt | grep % | tr -d " " | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d% -f1`
                if [[ "$PASS" -ge 95 ]]
                then
                    exit 0
                else
                    exit 1
                fi
            '''
```

But it constantly gives me an error

```
16:01:00 + cat index.txt
16:01:00 + grep %
16:01:00 + cut -d% -f1
16:01:00 + tr -d  
16:01:00 + cut -d: -f2
16:01:00 + PASS= 100
16:01:00 /home/xxxx/script.sh: 100: not found
```

What's happened? Anyone could help? Thanks

Comment: get rid of the space after `PASS=`.  at the moment, your script is setting PASS to the empty string and then trying to execute the result of the `cat .....` (which in your example evaluates to 100).  so it is effectively `PASS="" 100`

Comment: @cas Oh man you saved my life LOL, you should put is as Answer instead of comment. Oh ya, another thing is use single `[` instead of double `[[`

Comment: Additionally, the whole of the `if` statement could be replaced by `[ "$PASS" -gt 95 ]`.  Neither `exit` statements are necessary as the test returns the correct exit status by itself (by virtue of being the last thing executed).

Comment: @JeffPang it's a dupe question, so i can't. And if i did answer, i'd have to comment on your use of backticks instead of `$(...)` and that awful pipeline of `cat | grep | tr | cut | cut` instead of just using awk or perl. or maybe sed.